# Iterate the test object map

Tags: rft

Is it possible to iterate the test object map within RFT? I have several (imported) object maps, and would like as well as a list of TestObjects - I would like to be able to look for the existence of the test object in a given map. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getMap()` to get the object map, then use `elements()` to get an `Enumeration` you can iterate over:

```
Enumeration mappedObjects = getMap().elements();
while (mappedObjects.hasMoreElements()) {
    mappedObjects.nextElement(); // do something with it...
}
```

If you have the test object name, you can also use `getMappedTestObject(objName)` to get an object directly from the map. It throws an `ObjectNotInMapException` when the object is not in the map.